# What is max amount of Firebase unique short dynamic links?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm creating short links such as

```
https://example.page.link/4Xyz
```

using [Firebase short links API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest)

The unique part of a link has 4 chars (upperCase letters, lowerCase and numbers allowed). As far as i understand it gives us only ~ 500k unique combinations. What will be if i over exceed this amount?

Comment: no, that question is about requests rate limits, not absolute amount of possible links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short unique codes are generated as needed, and can be longer than 4 characters.

There is no documented limit to the number of dynamic links you can generate. There may be a physical limit, but there's nothing in the code limiting it.